# Is Debian 0777 permission octal safe for use with a web server?

Tags: debian, permissions

it seems that the only way I can get PHP applications to work is through giving each file 0777 permissions. Is this safe for a web server environment?

i.e. Will *anyone* be able to edit my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having daemons, i.e. a web server, run as a non-root user gives you a layer of protection if that particular executable is compromised.  (Note that "forking" servers such as `apache` have one process that runs as root and worker subprocesses that do not.  This is needed so that `apache` can bind to a privileged (<1024) port number.)

If your webserver is `apache` for example, and it runs as `www-data:www-data`, someone who finds and then takes advantage of an exploit can only have the same privileges as the `www-data` user or `www-data` group.  It can also only access files that are owned by `www-data` user, owned by the `www-data` group, or world readable/writeable/executable.

Having PHP scripts *modifiable* (i.e. write permission) by `www-data` would mean an attacker who got in by way of your HTTP daemon could then replace that script with any code he/she wants.  PHP scripts should not need to be modifiable by `www-data` unless they are badly written or not meant to run in the context of a web server (which is rare).

You may want certain *directories* modifiable if the application saves data or otherwise uses the filesystem.  I usually symlink these off to something off the main filesystem.  Even then, for complete security you do not want `www-data:www-data` to be able to write new files into anything that your HTTP daemon will call PHP from.  `apache`, through the use of `.htaccess` files and `<Directory>` stanzas in the config files can be configured to not execute PHP in certain directories - if you want to be really comprehensive about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Anyone will be able to edit your files.  Thats what the last "7" means.

Without knowing your application, I'm guessing maybe what you want is permission 775 on those files which are supposed to be read/written to through the application, and ensure that the group is set to the apache user.    Even so, be aware that if something is compromised on that box, people can probably still read and write those files - there is no simple way around this.  (You can manage the problem a number of ways, but none are simple).

Comment: I'm running nginx, and it appears that it runs through a user called www-data. Should I give the group permissions to that? If so, then why can't I see it in the users list in some places?

Comment: Probably, and I don't know what you mean by "If so, then why can't I see it in the users list in some places? ".  If the system recognises the user - simplisticly speaking if they have an entry in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow then the user exists.  Yes, www-data is probably the correct user (but I have never looked at nginx)

Comment: The userlist problem is likely something with WinSCP. Sometimes www-data will not display in the group/owner list for files. But yes, assigned permissions and stuff works so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered pretty well over at [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338641/in-a-php-apache-linux-context-why-exactly-is-chmod-777-dangerous).

You need to look in to suexec. It's a pain to setup if you don't know what you're doing, but it can help isolate breaches by letting apache access files as a user.